# CSS style sheet not working on Dynamics content on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in web development. I have made dynamics element. A chat box which shows on click. The div for this chat box is created on click.

Everything works well. But this chat box does not pick css styles already in place in style sheet.

Is something i need to know?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Please paste some part of your code. Or create a fiddle

Comment: Please read the [help] and take the [tour] so you can get a better understanding on how to ask a good question. Without seeing your code we would be taking wild guesses at solving the problem. [mcve] are very helpful in helping us help you.

Comment: it is data driven. I am posting another question in a while with code. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Please see link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104927/css-file-not-working-on-dynamics-content-elements