# CSS rules not being applied to dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have dynamic created box, which should appear on click. It works ok, but css style sheet is not picking dynamic elements. Please see msg_head. The box consists of msg_head, msg_body and msg_footer.
Thanks.

**JS**

```
var parent = document.getElementById('ft');

var mbox = document.createElement('div');
mbox.id='mb';
mbox.className='msg_box';

var mhead = document.createElement('div');
var mx = document.createElement('div');

mhead.id='bb';
mhead.className='msg_head';
mx.id='x'
mx.className='close';


var mbody = document.createElement('div');
mbody.className = 'msg_body';

var mfoot=document.createElement('div');
mfoot.className='msg_footer';

var mheadall=mhead.appendChild(mx);  

mbox.appendChild(mhead).appendChild(mx);
mbox.appendChild(mbody);
mbox.appendChild(mfoot);  

parent.appendChild(mbox);
var tt = $(this).text();


var  dd = $(this).attr("id");  

$("#bb").text(tt);

$("#bb").attr("id",dd);         


});

})
```

**CSS**

```
.close {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
}

.leftblock {
    position:relative;
}

.msg_box {

    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    bottom:-5px;
    height:200px;
    width:250px; 
    background:white;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:35px;

}

.msg_head {
    background:#3498db; 
    width:250px;
    color:white;
    padding:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
} 

.msg_body {
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:15px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.msg_input {
    width:280px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.nameid {
    cursor: pointer; 
    position:relative;
    padding:5px 10px;
}


.footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:20px;
    bottom:0;
    width:84%;
    height:342px;
    background:yellow;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

**HTML (with PHP elements)**

```
</html>
<body>

    <div class="container">

    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="leftblock"> 
    </div>

    <div class="chat_box" id="cb">

        <div class="chat_head">Members</div>
        <div class="chat_body">
            <?php
            for($i=1;$usernamee=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records); $i++)
            {
                echo  "<div class='nameid' id='$i' 
            <b>".$usernamee['username']."</br>"."</b></div>";

            }


            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ft" class="footer">
    </div>


    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: @karthick It's mangled in that mess

Comment: Better use [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim3Yzq24LUAhWIpo8KHaC8ATIQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w) instead of `live()`

Comment: Please format your code properly and present it fully in the future. You can avoid most problems by creating readable and sustainable code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", '.nameid', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var parent = document.getElementById('ft');

    var mbox = document.createElement('div');
    mbox.id = 'mb';
    mbox.className = 'msg_box';

    var mhead = document.createElement('div');
    var mx = document.createElement('div');

    mhead.id = 'bb';
    mhead.className = 'msg_head';
    mx.id = 'x'
    mx.className = 'close';


    var mbody = document.createElement('div');
    mbody.className = 'msg_body';

    var mfoot = document.createElement('div');
    mfoot.className = 'msg_footer';

    var mheadall = mhead.appendChild(mx);

    mbox.appendChild(mhead).appendChild(mx);
    mbox.appendChild(mbody);
    mbox.appendChild(mfoot);

    parent.appendChild(mbox);
    var tt = $(this).text();


    var dd = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#bb").text(tt);

    $("#bb").attr("id", dd);


});
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/sx1bcxax/5/)